# Output last command

Tags: function, terminal, zsh

I am using a function that I found in [YADR](https://github.com/skwp/dotfiles) which should insert the output of the last command.

```
# Use Ctrl-x,Ctrl-l to get the output of the last command
zmodload -i zsh/parameter
insert-last-command-output() {
LBUFFER+="$(eval $history[$((HISTCMD-1))])"
}
zle -N insert-last-command-output
bindkey "^X^L" insert-last-command-output
```

For some reason, it does not seem to work by pressing `ctrl-x ctrl-l` but running

`echo $(eval $history[$((HISTCMD-1))])`

command on the terminal does produce the output of the last command.

Running `bindkey -M viins` shows `"^X^L" insert-last-command-output`
 as one of the entries. Therefore, the function is registered.

I don't really understand how the function works. I think that the variable `LBUFFER` holds the output of all last commands but when I `echo $LBUFFER`, it returns the function code.

Can anyone help me get this working?

Comment: It works with my config. It works also with only your code in my zshrc. Try to use an empty config file to see. FYI it does not insert the output of the last command, it executes the last command again and insert the output.

Comment: @rools: You are right; with an empty config it works. What is the quickest way to find out what in my zsh setup is causing the problem? I thought that because `bindkey -M` shows the correct binding that it should work.

Comment: I do not have a better solution than "dichotomy".

Comment: In some cases placing the function at the end of your zshrc will make it work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found a solution.

I had been trying to use the shortcut inside tmux which did not work. However, outside tmux, everything worked. It turns out that tmux will not allow a shortcut with two keys. I changed the shortcut to just `alt-L` and everything works.